# What's the correct way to set up multiple Web Apps behind Azure Front Door?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-front-door

I have three backend pools, 1 is an API and 2 are Web Apps.  I've set up routing in Azure Front Door to route to the correct areas, but how do I modify the web apps to use the Front Door URL for all of the links without having to hardcode them all manually?

For example, if the Front Door URL is frontdoor.azurefd.net but Web App 1 is published to webapp1.azurewebsites.net how can I set the root url of webapp1 such that all of the Razor Areas actually link to frontdoor.azurefd.net/webapp1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the different backend pool based on the path URL with Azure front door, you must make sure the virtual path existence. For example, you have to add the virtual directory `/webapp1` in your app service  like this:
[image]

So you could access your webapp1 via URL `https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/webapp1`. Then you could add `/webapp1/*` or `/webapp1` in the **PATTERNS TO MATCH** and modify the **Forwarding protocol** is `match request` in your routing rule.
[image]

After this, you could access the URL `frontdoor.azurefd.net/webapp1` for your webapp1. The same configuration is for the other two backends and routing rules.

For more reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching

Comment: Is it possible to add virtual paths with Function Apps? I'm only finding it possible with the App Service.

Comment: This does not work for mew. When I have two virtual applications in the same Web App, I get "HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process".

Comment: To get rid of 500.35 you also have to change to OutOfProcess hosting: `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` Worked for me 