# Setting up multiple web apps behind one Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have two app services, WebApp1 and WebApp2 that are using a multi-region architecture.

In Region1:

- WebApp1
- WebApp2

In Region2:

- WebApp1
- WebApp2

Architecture:

[image]

**This two web apps are completely separate and independent to each other ( but share the same database) and both will have it's own custom domain.** The URL that should be exposed to the end user is something like this.

- WebApp1 -- www.webapp1.com
- WebApp2 -- www.webapp2.com

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877692/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-multiple-web-apps-behind-azure-front-door) but this is not meeting my requirement. These two apps need to be deployed as independent application, not as the virtual application(if this is not the only way).

I don't want to use multiple AFD for this purpose? Is it possible to achieve my requirement using a single AFD? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create 2 Frontend host (Custom domain) and place web app1 in a backend pool and web App2 another backend pool.

You can create 2 separate rules for each App. It should work as you described in the diagram mentioned above.

If you have any issues with the configuration, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, in the provided diagram, I don't have any load balancing requirement hence how can we achieve the same without doing any load balancing with 2 frontdoors?

Comment: If you need primary secondary setup, while creating rules, specify a backend to send all traffic.

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify even if the apps are in two separate front doors they can [share the same WAF Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/afds-overview)