# Routing to multiple Web Apps behind Azure Front Door

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have two backend pools in my front door. One is configured for App Service AAA and the second one is configured for service BBB:

- aaa.azurewebsites.net
- bbb.azurewebsites.net

I'm adding two routing rules, one for backend pool AAA and the second one for backend pool BBB with the next patterns to match:

Backend pool AAA:

1. /*
2. /aaa/*

Backend pool BBB:

1. /bbb/*

That's it for rules, so no Rules Engine configuration is set, Route Type is "Forward" and URL rewrite/Caching are disabled.

Now, I'm trying to access my backends:

- fd.azurefd.net/web-method-of-aaa - it works and calls web method
  named "web-method-of-aaa" from backend aaa
- fd.azurefd.net/aaa/web-method-of-aaa - returns 404
- fd.azurefd.net/bbb/web-method-of-bbb - returns 404

What am I missing here? I've found [one option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56877692/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-multiple-web-apps-behind-azure-front-door), but it can't be used in my case because my Web Apps are deployed from Container Registry so I can't add virtual directory in the App Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So everything works if routing rules configured the next way:

Rule for backend pool AAA:

```
Patterns to match: /aaa/*
URL Rewrite: enabled
Custom forwarding path: /
```

Rule for backend pool BBB:

```
Patterns to match: /bbb/*
URL Rewrite: enabled
Custom forwarding path: /
```

Comment: I have exact same scenario with azure front door, the difference that web apps are SPA built with VUE.js and hosted in netlify. I am having problem with site not getting fully loaded. It loads the index.html but not the css and js files, hence the app is not working. any suggestions ?

Comment: @Walnut I had the same issue. When you configure your backend pool, make sure that 'backend host name' is set to the URL domain of your app service (without 'https:// ' prefix). When you do this, the 'backend host type' will change to 'Custom Host' instead of 'App Service' and you should be able to route to it based on the route map as recommended by Igor